# Managing .htaccess file in LAMP, Debian 10 Buster

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set up LAMP in Debian 10 Buster for hosting my website. It has the following features

1. Firstly, user will be sent to Login page
2. If the login is successful, a folder will be created for him in the server to save his corresponding data.
3. When he logs out of the site, his directory will be deleted.

The problem is as the user remains logged in, his directory will exist. So others might have access to his data in his folder. So, I must make sure that all the files in this temporary folder can be accessible only if the variable `$_SESSION['email']` is equal to his email id
I read that we can use `.htaccess` file for this purpose. How should I configure the `.htaccess` file in the folder? Should I make any more extra configurations with Apache? Also what are the commands I have to include in `.htaccess` file?
Thanks in Prior to the help

Comment: If you create this directory outside of the web root, then you can control it through your application.

Comment: @Nigel but i need to create this directory in the web root and restrict it's access using .htaccess file. Is there a way?